# Xamarin Forms TranslateTo relative to parent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using TranslateTo to move an object vertically on the screen, but I only see how to use numbers for the x/y arguments.  How can I do something like when adding an object on a view where you say, "Constraint.RelativeToParent(..."?

CAN I translate relative to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a `RelativeLayout` perhaps?

There is a discussion [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17742/relativelayout-in-xaml), and a demo [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/RelativeLayoutDemoPage.cs) that may get you started?

Yes - you can perform a `Translate` operation on a `View` that is relative to some other `View`.

The following example demonstrates that:-

```
        StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        };

        RelativeLayout objRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objRelativeLayout);

        Label objLabel1 = new Label();
        objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        objLabel1.Text = "This is a label";
        objLabel1.SizeChanged += ((o2, e2) =>
        {
            objRelativeLayout.ForceLayout();
        });
        objRelativeLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1,
            xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return ((parent.Width - objLabel1.Width) / 2);
            }));

        Button objButton = new Button();
        objButton.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        objButton.Text = "Hi";
        objRelativeLayout.Children.Add(objButton,
            xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(objLabel1,
            new Func<RelativeLayout, View, double>((pobjRelativeLayout, pobjView) =>
            {
                return pobjView.X + pobjView.Width;
            })));

        Button objButton1 = new Button();
        objButton1.Text = "Translate the button that is relative to the text";
        objButton1.Clicked += ((o2, e2) =>
        {
            objButton.TranslateTo(100,100,2000);
        });
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton1);

        Button objButton2 = new Button();
        objButton2.Text = "Change label text";
        objButton2.Clicked += ((o2, e2) =>
        {
            objLabel1.Text = "text";
        });
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton2);
```

Clicking on the button with text "Translate the button that is relative to the text" will translate the blue button by 100 width and 100 height.

The rule is still enforced when you click the button with text "Change label text".  Note that the translation previously applied is still at an offset of 100 width and 100 height from the end of the `Label` that we are doing our relative layout against.

Comment: I am using a relative view, I failed to mention that.  The solution I ended up using was to get the length (the height in this case) of the view I wanted to move relative to, so it looks like double range = image_graph.Height (image_graph is the view to move relative TO).  Then, I got the percentage of how far up the graph the object should be, did some dividing, and then did TranslateTo.